# Double/half inverted egrep

Tags: grep

I'd like to show all lines *except* those containing `foo`, *unless they also contain `bar`*. [Logically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+%28a+and+not+b%29) `!(foo and (!bar)) === (!foo) or bar`, so I can use two separate expressions. Can I do this sort of match with a single `grep` or `egrep`? `-v` doesn't work, since it negates both expressions, and I probably can't use Perl regex.

The following works, but it would be much less work to convert the code if it could be done in `egrep`:

```
$ echo '
foo
bar
moofoo
foobar
barbar' | grep -Pv '^((?!bar).)*foo((?!bar).)*$'

bar
foobar
barbar
```

The issue at hand is speed (looking for patterns in gigabytes of data).

Comment: wow my brain hurts just looking at that one. Good question. Out of curiosity why are you restricted from using Perl regex? Does your egrep not support -P?

Comment: @Dave G: `egrep -P` is the same as `pgrep` or `grep -P`, so that won't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using awk is fine then following gives desired output

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "};
           {
               if ($0 ~ /(foo)/) 
               {
                    if ($0 ~ /(bar)/) 
                    {
                       print $0
                    } 
               } 
               else 
               {
                    print $0
               }
           }' FileContainingText.txt
```

since this works per line and no pipes are involved this should be fast.